# Visual Studio 2013 Git Source Control Files Read Only?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a project in VS2013 with Git enabled through "Microsoft Git Provider". today when I open the project, all the source code files are locked with read only. I can not save any changes.

Why they are locked to read only? I tried reboot and only program accessing those files is VS.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change to Git simply by changing the provider in Visual Studio. The TFS server provides two manually exclusive source control systems. TFVC is the default and is a SVCS. Git is a new DVCS option.

If your Team Project on the server was created with TFVC that is what you have to use client side. You can create a new Team Project with Git as the choice or you can use TFVC.

Workaround (advanced): You can use the Git-TF command line tool to clone a TFVC folder to a local Git repo. You can also use it to push back to TFVC however this is a lossy function.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the original question.  

The question is effectively, 

"Why is MS GIT defaulting to read-only?  Git does not operate on an exclusive lock basis, what gives? How do I fix this?"

Comment: And my first paragraph answers that question... Second paragraph is an inferred stretch issue, with a work around...